# Standard OO Abstraction for Humans / Persons

Tags: oop, standards, abstraction, personalization

I've found myself reinventing a particular wheel **way** too often; and I was wondering if there was any sort of standardization that I could draw upon. Specifically, I find myself creating things like:

```
class Name(dict):
    family, first, middle, prefixes, suffixes, titles, etc.

class Person(object):
    name, dob, address, etc...

class Client(Person):
    account_id, billing_address, intake_date, etc.

class Employee(Person):
    tax_id, supervisor, roles, etc.
```

Now, obviously, the bits of relevant data to every use case are different; but, in the interest of consistency and interoperability, there have to be *some* standards relating to the abstraction of human persons in software.

I am seeking a generally applicable base abstraction so that I can write consistent, interoperable and readable "people" classes in c++, Python, Java or whatever. Any guidance?

--- EDIT ---

Though, as mentioned, the relevant "person" data tends to vary from one problem domain or use case to another, there are also consistencies between almost all domains that deal with abstractions of humans. Additionally, my experience is that what starts as a simple program addressing a small, well-defined problem domain often evolves into a much more complex application that needs to interoperate or exchange data with programs that deal with very different problem domains.

Since a huge amount of software needs to use an abstraction of "person" in one way or another, and since some of the core bits of data about humans can be expressed quite differently across languages and cultures; having a reference standard for person data could make life much easier as simple programs grow into complex ones.

Comment: There is no such thing as "some standards relating to the abstraction of human persons" because it all depends on the problem domain.

Comment: @PeeHaa: While your explanation touches a right point, that applies to almost everything, and yet we often manage to compile useful standards that can be used across problem domains. In this particular case, [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/) can be seen as a step toward this direction.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Interesting... Isn't that limiting fast though? (Nope didn't read the entire thing :P)

Comment: @PeeHaa: It always depends on what you're doing. As many reusable things, it's designed to help for the standard cases, while special cases may either need something entirely new, or a non-standard extension to the standardized core. For an example you may be more used to, think of the address books in e-mail software - these may be used for a large variety of different purposes (just storing private contacts, tracking business contacts, keeping track of contacts with their birthdays, ...), and yet standardized address books are always used, and - where required - integrated with other things.

Comment: It's an interesting concept. TIL about FOAF

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: If you think that FOAF might be relevant, please suggest it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The closest standard I can think of is the VCARD standard.

That being said different industries have standards for representing people that is generally far more useful than vCard. For example recruiting has HR-XML.